# Select statement across multiple years grouping in periods spanning leap year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, leap-year

I have this query which selects all records spanning iMAXYears until 30 Nov 2012:

```
 SELECT sum([AllocatedAmount]) as total, 
 datediff(day,transactiondate,'30 Nov 2012') / DaysInyear AS YearDiff 
 FROM tblGroups 
 AND datediff(day,transactiondate, '30 Nov 2012') / DaysInyear < iMaxYears
 AND not transactiondate > '30 Nov 2012'  
 GROUP BY g.groupdescription, nominal, 
 datediff(day,transactiondate, '30 Nov 2012') / DaysInyear
```

for the purposes of this question 30 Nov 2012 is hardcoded (variable name= lMaxDate) and iMaxYears is 3

My problem is that DaysInYear will normally have a value of 365 but in a leap year will have a value of 366.

In a leap year such as 2012, the above statement doesnt pick up 01 dec 2011 because of 29 feb 2012.

I know

```
DaysInYear=(CASE WHEN (year % 4 = 0 AND year % 100 <> 0) 
OR year % 400 = 0 then 366 else 365)

Currently DaysInYear = 365.
```

Should I create a function

```
DaysInYear(lYear) where you pass in a year (lYear) 
and it returns 365 or 366?
```

Problem is i cant pass Year(transactiondate) as the year will always span part of 2 years and iMaxYears means that we could have 4 annual periods in the resultset.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: you are doing this for lets say span of 3 or 4 years then daysinyear is based on current year right? or it has all the 3 or 4 years days

Answer (score 0):

What if you just use that case statement in place of the DaysInYear variable?

```
    SELECT sum([AllocatedAmount]) as total, 
 datediff(day,transactiondate,'30 Nov 2012') / CASE WHEN (year % 4 = 0 AND year % 100 <> 0) 
OR year % 400 = 0 then 366 else 365 end AS YearDiff 
 FROM tblGroups 
 AND datediff(day,transactiondate, '30 Nov 2012') / CASE WHEN (year % 4 = 0 AND year % 100 <> 0) 
OR year % 400 = 0 then 366 else 365 end < iMaxYears
 AND not transactiondate > '30 Nov 2012'  
 GROUP BY g.groupdescription, nominal, 
 datediff(day,transactiondate, '30 Nov 2012') / CASE WHEN (year % 4 = 0 AND year % 100 <> 0) 
OR year % 400 = 0 then 366 else 365 end
```

So long as the value of days in Year is based on the transaction date in question, you should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the cutoff point to the first of January if you remove 29 days and 10 months from the transactionDate. This way, DATEADD calculates the right amount of days to subtract for you.

```
CREATE FUNCTION yearDiff(@maxDate DATE, @transactionDate DATE)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @dayDiff INT
  DECLARE @monthDiff INT

  -- Determine how many months and days @maxDate is from the first of january
  SET @monthDiff = 1 - DATEPART(MONTH, @maxDate)
  SET @dayDiff = 1 - DATEPART(DAY, @maxDate)

  -- Determine how many years away from @maxDate the transaction is
  RETURN DATEDIFF(YEAR,
                  DATEADD(MONTH,
                          @monthDiff,
                          DATEADD(DAY,
                                  @dayDiff,
                                  @transactionDate)
                          ),
                  @maxDate
                  )
END
```

I think your select would then look like this:

```
SELECT
  sum(amount) [total],
  dbo.yearDiff(@maxDate, transactionDate) [yearDiff]
FROM tblGroups
WHERE  transactionDate <= @maxDate
AND dbo.yearDiff(@maxDate, transactionDate) <= @iMaxYears
GROUP BY dbo.yearDiff(@maxDate, transactionDate)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/54c2d/2

Advantage is that it's nice and readable and you have no magic numbers. It is not particularly efficient, you 'll want to inline the function calls or maybe add a computed column for the yearDiff if there's really many transactions.